# How Contract Method Works in Changing State Variable?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

So, I'm trying to implement openzeppelin [ERC721Enumerable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol) contract. I want to override `_beforeTokenTransfer` method. Because it was a Hook, I have to call `super` method like this

```js
function _beforeTokenTransfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 tokenId
)
    internal
    virtual
    override
{
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);

    // some requirement
    require(someRequirement(_msgSender()), 'MyERC721: Sender has not met the requirement to proceed')

   // some stuff
}
```

The problem is, inside `_beforeTokenTransfer` of `ERC721Enumerable`, there are some changing state variables. I am worried that when my method reverted, the state variables there are changed before are not going back to their previous state. Usually, something like this will happened

```py
>>> class SomeClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.state = 0
...     def change_state(self, x):
...         self.state += x
...         raise Exception('method reverted')
>>> an_instance = SomeClass()
>>> an_instance.state
0
>>> an_instance.change_state(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in change_state
Exception: method reverted
>>> an_instance.state
10
```

The state variable inside `SomeClass` is changed because the exception is raised after the state changed. Does this also valid for SmartContract? How does SmartContract handle changing state before exception is raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context it doesn't make much difference when the exception is raised. Transactions are atomic: either they succeed fully or they are fully reverted back.

So if there is a revert anywhere in the execution path, the whole transaction is reverted back, and all changes made by it are reverted. (This is not 100% correct: external contracts' revertions can be for example caught by try-catch blocks.)

So you don't really need to worry about some residual state changes.

Comment: "external contracts' revertions can be for example caught by try-catch blocks". Could you please elaborate this. Does this mean that if you try-catch the exception, the state could be changed?

Comment: With try-catch the whole transaction doesn't need to revert, if an external call reverts. It's up to you to decide. https://blog.ethereum.org/2020/01/29/solidity-0.6-try-catch/

Comment: What I mean is if someone calls my contract from his contract dan does try-catch inside it, does the state from my contract would change because the exception caught by his contract?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand the question. And in any case, please post a new question if you have more question - or search among the existing questions

Comment: Following up to @fahadh4ilyas, the state would only change if the 'try' within the try/catch passed requirements needed in order to fulfill the tx.